# check_ajax_reffer not working when logged

Tags: ajax, security

When I'm logged, the code works perfect, but if no logged, check_ajax_reffer fails.

First, pass ajax_url and nonce's':

```
wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'security_price'  => wp_create_nonce('ga_price'), 'security_arquivo'  => wp_create_nonce('ga_arquivo') ) );
```

And then simply validate:

```
if ($data == null && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' )) {
    check_ajax_referer('ga_price', 'security_price');
    ...
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Have you considered using the newer modern REST API endpoints? They do all of this for you so you don't have to

Comment: Entire plugin has already developed, only this issue exists :/

Comment: Are you sure check_ajax_referer is the problem? Have you hooked `wp_ajax_npriv_` as well as `wp_ajax_`?

Comment: Yes: $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_ga_real_price', $plugin_public, 'get_real_price' );
  $this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ga_real_price', $plugin_public, 'get_real_price' );```

Comment: @Lucisu can you edit your question to include that snippet and the surrounding context? Keep in mind that REST API requests are still AJAX, it's just using a smaller/simpler API, your code will be smaller simpler and faster. Additionally, can you describe how you tested this? It's not clear how you're verifying that check ajax referrer is what failed. I also don't see the javascript that makes the request to the server